# Apache camel. InterceptSendTo doesn't work with bean endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I can't understand why my tests don't work. I try intercept and skip sending to endpoint which is bean reference and nothing happens.
I'm using version 2.16.2.

test-camel.xml

```
<bean id="eb" class="com.rencap.emf.bpipe.EndpointBean"/>    
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">  
    <camel:endpoint id="requestEP" uri="direct:request"/>
    <endpoint id="beanEP" uri="bean:eb?method=processMessage" />
    <camel:route id="testRoute">
        <camel:from ref="requestEP"/>
        <camel:to ref="beanEP" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

EndpointBean.java

```
package com.rencap.emf.bpipe;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class EndpointBean {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EndpointBean.class);

    public void processMessage( String msg ){
        LOG.info("Processing message: {} ",msg);
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
@EndpointInject(ref="requestEP")
ProducerTemplate requestEP;
@EndpointInject(ref="beanEP")
ProducerTemplate beanEP;
@Autowired
ModelCamelContext camelContext; 
@Test
public void test() throws Exception{

    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("testRoute").adviceWith( camelContext , new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint( beanEP.getDefaultEndpoint().getEndpointUri() ).
                to("mock:send").
                skipSendToOriginalEndpoint();
        }
    });     
    TestUtils.waitingFor("Configuration applied", 2000);

    MockEndpoint mockEP = camelContext.getEndpoint("mock:send",MockEndpoint.class);
    mockEP.setExpectedCount( 1 );

    requestEP.sendBody("Message");

    mockEP.assertIsSatisfied();

    TestUtils.waitingFor("All rows commited", 2000);
}
```

Test always fails.
Logs:

```
13:11:02.512 [main] INFO  o.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition - AdviceWith route after: Route(testRoute)[[From[ref:requestEP]] -> [InterceptSendToEndpoint[bean://eb?method=processMessage -> [To[mock:send]]], To[ref:beanEP]]]
13:11:02.537 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: testRoute started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://request]
13:11:02.538 [main] INFO  com.rencap.emf.bpipe.test.TestUtils - Wait 2000 ms. Configuration applied 
13:11:04.554 [main] INFO  com.rencap.emf.bpipe.EndpointBean - Processing message: Message 
13:11:04.556 [main] INFO  o.a.c.component.mock.MockEndpoint - Asserting: Endpoint[mock://send] is satisfied
```

It means that sending to endpoint isn't being intercepted and skipped. May be I don't understand something but I coudn't find any restriction on use this method.

In additional I noticed the same problem for endpoint with log. If I replace beanEP on :

```
<endpoint id="beanEP" uri="log:LOGMESSAGE" />
```

that I receive the same result.
But if I replace it on

```
<endpoint id="beanEP" uri="seda:send" />
```

and add new route :

```
<camel:route id="route2">
        <camel:from ref="sendEP"/>
        <camel:log message="msg received ${body}"/>
    </camel:route>
```

that I will get expected result and test will be successed.

What do I do wrong? Or maybe Are there some restrictions on this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was adviced to override isUseAdviceWith. In my case It's look like:

```
public class TestTest extends  CamelSpringTestSupport {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        Endpoint beanEP    = context.getEndpoint("beanEP");
        Endpoint requestEP = context.getEndpoint("requestEP");
        context.getRouteDefinition("testRoute").adviceWith( context , new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint( beanEP.getEndpointUri() ).
                    to("mock:send").
                    skipSendToOriginalEndpoint();
            }
        });    
        context.start();
        TestUtils.waitingFor("Configuration applied", 2000);
        MockEndpoint mockEP = context.getEndpoint("mock:send",MockEndpoint.class);
        mockEP.setExpectedCount( 1 );
        context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody(requestEP, "Message");
        mockEP.assertIsSatisfied();
        TestUtils.waitingFor("All rows commited", 2000);
    }
    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-camel.xml");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

It works.

But I'd like to use annotations but [this](https://github.com/CamelCookbook/camel-cookbook-examples/blob/master/camel-cookbook-testing/src/test/java/org/camelcookbook/examples/testing/advicewith/FixedEndpointEnhancedSpringTest.java) isn't working now for me yet.

Comment: The overriding of ```isUseAdviceWith()``` was a good pointer! Thanks.